# React-Native Firebase Phone Auth freezes iPhone

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I want to sign the user in by phoneNumber in react-native. On Android this code snippet works neat. But on iOS always when I start this function the emulator freezes. I am trying to use this code [Auth-Example](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.3.x/auth/phone-auth) I am using the react-native-firebase library.

```
  openPhoneVerification() {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(this.state.phoneNumber)
      .then(confirmResult =>
        this.props.navigation.navigate("PhoneVerification", {
          confirmResult
        })
      )
      // Wrong number - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithPhoneNumber
      .catch(error =>
        Alert.alert(
          "Number not valid",
          "Please check your number and type in again",
          [
            {
              text: "OK",
              style: "cancel"
            }
          ],
          { cancelable: true }
        )
      );
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm encountering the same issue and am wondering if it's related to the fact that my app isn't prompting users to enable push notifications via testflight?

Answer (score -1):

Solution for anyone encountering the same issue:

Make sure that the name given to your APN matches the app name

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more pls ?

Comment: @Ethrak

I'll do my best since I haven't worked with firebase in almost a year and no longer have access to the repo (it was for a contract I finished off in September). I think the issue I had encountered was the I had misconfigured my APNs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs?authuser=0

The name I had listed in the APN was not the same as the app name I had in my RN app. I hope that helps, let me know if it ends up resolving your issue